# Using CSS coding to display print & email icon (and setting them to right float inline)

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have a question about my default print and email icons not displaying in my Joomla powered site.
I enabled them in the Joomla UI, but nothing than a list with both links is displayed.
As I was checking the web I found one reason that this could happen if your using a custom template, and the images are missing.

Now my question is how to get around that with CSS coding?

Thanks for any kind of hint or help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NJm8a/

Comment: I didn't see any reference to images for that list within your CSS or HTML

Comment: It's just a question that needs directions. I found that the class for the print icon is: "print-icon", now I have no idea how to trade the teyt with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you also want to remove the list formatting and your icon files are 16x16 pixel just add the following to your CSS file:

```
ul.actions {
    list-style:none;
    float:right
}
.print-icon, .email-icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    text-indent:-3000px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.print-icon {
    background-image:url(path/to/yourprintimage.png);
}
.email-icon {
    background-image:url(path/to/youremailimage.png);
}
```

Obviously replace the file names with actual icons ;)

Comment: I don't want to replace with my icons:) Thank you for helping:)